# Jobs bug adding favorites doesn't allow me to view them

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

Add any favorite jobs.  Click the link on the right to "view all" to view your jobs, the div grays out completely and doesn't show any jobs.  The div I am talking about is the one on the right that shows your recent searchs, your favorites, and your match preferences.

Just noticed it doesn't work with any number of favorites not just a lot!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on your developer console? if so, please add a screenshot.

Comment: Doesn't show any error on developer console. For me, the unique difference is that appears 1 favorite job instead of the 5 I have stored.